# Instance EC2 like a child subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain, amazon-route53

We're using Route53 DNS to point to an EC2 instance: name.domain.com, and we also need access this form: domain.com/name.

What is the correct form to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is not a DNS problem, instead it's a web server problem.

Create 2 Route53 `A` records:  one for name.domain.com and one for domain.com.  Both should point to the same IP address (your instance).

Getting your web server to recognize name.domain.com and domain.com/name as the same thing is dependent on your web server.